# Oracle SELECT 1

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have 2 table one main table with many informations and a subtable that has a FK for the first one. The second table has many lines with the same FK. I need to return 1(or true) if 2 values are diferent in the same line of this second table with this FK.

ex.:

```
SELECT MC.ID,
(SELECT SUM(qtd_send) FROM   subtable WHERE subtable_FK = MC.id) AS qtd_send, 
(SELECT SUM(qtd_received) FROM   subtable WHERE  subtable_FK = MC.id) AS qtd_received,
(SELECT 1 FROM subtable WHERE qtd_send = qtd_receivedAND subtable_FK = MC.ID) as OK
FROM   table MC;
```

This query did not work, the following message return:

"single-row subquery returns more than one row"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this subquery:

```
(SELECT 1 FROM subtable WHERE qtd_send = qtd_received AND subtable_FK = MC.ID) as OK
```

I believe what you want is:

```
(case when exists (SELECT 1 FROM subtable WHERE qtd_send = qtd_received AND subtable_FK = MC.ID) 
      then 1
      else 0
 end) as OK
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work the way I wanted, so I changed the sign = to <> and it worked. Thank you Gordon.